# htaccess rule is messing with session variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I'm having an issue with session variables. The site is currently hosted on 000webhost. Below is my htaccess file inside the root of "public_html" folder `\public_html\.htaccess`

```
php_flag output_buffering on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The sessions are being stored in "tmp" folder at the public_html level `\tmp`

I'm using the below code in the index.php inside public_html folder `\public_html\index.php` to manage a fetch API CORS

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
......
$urlpath = explode("/",rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

The `$urlpath` variable will define what page will load. I'm serving static assets from `assets` folder and PHP pages from different folder (ex: `platform1`,`platform2`) and all of them are at the save level as the above htaccess file `\public_html\assets` & `\public_html\platform1`

The PHP files inside the `platform1` folder create and store session variables so they can be accessed across multiple pages.

The problem now is if the htaccess rules are provided, session variables are not stored. If I remove the rewrite rules, session variables work perfectly.

I'm not adept at PHP functions, especially with the htaccess rewrite rules. One non-ideal way is to generate all the session variables on every page load which increases the page load times and such I'd like to keep this as a last resort.

Comment: What parameters does your session cookie get set with? Especially the `session.cookie_path`.

Comment: And are we talking about "normal" requests that are having this problem, or CORS requests?

Comment: @CBroe , all requests have this issue. The session files get created but are 0bytes in size with 644 permissions

Comment: Storing session variables is the responsibility of PHP, and it does so on the local file system. It has nothing to do with external URLs, cookies, or anything in an `.htaccess` file. You have not provided any code showing use of the session, or given examples of what requests are causing problems for you.

Comment: Do you also include the `php_flag output_buffering on` in your toggle of the .htaccess rules that determines success? What is the goal of your rewrite-rules?

Comment: @cyberbrain I'm trying to parse the url path and do certain functions without using laravel. This is in my index.php `$urlpath = explode("/",rawurldecode(str_replace("/dummy_path","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));`

Comment: Sorry, probably a misunderstanding, but you didn't answer my questions: 1) When you are trying with and without your .htaccess rewrite rules, do you also try with and without the `php_flag` option? And 2) what is the purpose of the .htaccess `RewriteRule` for you? (Maybe there is an alternative...) And now I also have a 3rd question: 3) Does a Laravel application create the session? (Probably best if you add all 3 answers as context description to your question)

Comment: @cyberbrain #1 I have to add `php_flag output_buffering on` because the hosting provider turns it off by default and I read on the provider forums threat that it's required for `$_SESSION` to work. #2 The `RewriteRule` is to send any and all non-asset traffic to the index.php for rerouting. #3 There is no Laravel. I tried to implement express js routing mechanism in PHP without using Laravel.

Comment: Ok, your `RewriteRule` looks a bit weird to me: the first parameter is a regular expression and it will replace each(!) character of the URL with a complete "index.php" string and will not pass anything of the original URL to the index.php. So can you specify some examples of what should be rewritten and what results you expect? I suppose you cannot increase the logging level of mod_rewrite to get some insights, what really happens? (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging )

Comment: what if you put ```session_start()``` within ```index.php``` instead of within the php files in the sub folders?